# Nextjs 13 error messages unhelpful, how to better understand nextjs errors?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Recently converted a vanilla react app to nextjs 13. Of course, nextjs offers some really powerful features. Why, though, are its error messages so unhelpful?

I don't have much of a clue where this error is happening nor is there much being conveyed in the error message itself.

[image]

Unhelpful^

[image]

the terminal outputs no error...

what gives?

Comment: What were you doing it throws that error? Could you share more info?

Comment: thats the problem, I don't know - I converted my app and starting chipping away at all the errors, this is what was left